# Show me the way to calling my function

Tags: python, python-2.x

So I'm learning to code and I started with Python.
I've learned the very basics of programming in python, like what are variables, operators, some functions etc.

I have this code:

```
def guessGame():
    import random
    guesses = 0
    randomNo = random.randint(0, 100)
    print "I think of a number between 0 and 100, you have 10 guesses to get it right!"
    while guesses < 10:
        guess = input("Take a guess ")
        guess = int(guess)
        guesses += 1
        if guess < randomNo:
            print "The number is higher than your guess"
        if guess > randomNo:
            print "The number is lower than your guess"
        if guess == randomNo:
            break
    if guess == randomNo:
        guesses = str(guesses)
        print "You got it in %s guesses!" % guesses
    if guess != randomNo:
        print "You failed to guess!"
guessGame()
```

when I run the code in cmd it just ends before the function gets "recalled".
[cmd output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwSrp.png)

Comment: Also it looks like you are using python 2.x? In that case you will want to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with the output you're getting? Looks good to me.

Comment: Looks ok with python `3.4.3`

Comment: Shouldn't it start over after getting the result, hence the "guessGame()" line.

Comment: I see now -- you expected the game to call itself.  You would need to indent that line to make it part of the function (as an earlier comment suggested you check).  However, this is *not* a good way to repeat something -- recursion is when you're breaking the problem down into a smaller version of the same thing.  Mere repetition suggests a simple loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called the game only once in your main program -- which consists of the last line only.  It runs the game once and quits.  There is no second call in your code.  Perhaps you want a classic "play again?" loop:

```
play = True
while play:
    guessGame()
    play = lower(raw_input("Play again?")[0]) == 'y'
```

after each game, you ask the player for input.  If that input begins with the letter 'y' (upper or lower case), then you continue playing; otherwise, play becomes False and you drop out of the loop.

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, of course. That actually makes sense ... Thaks ^^

Comment: Hey I tried to do it my way, could you check it for me: http://pastebin.com/4bBbUazW and is there a way I could get your contact if I needed a quick code check .. dw I google a lot so it won't be that often ^^

Comment: The new function should be called from your main program, not from the game.  You're making the recursion mistake I talked about.